# Store User Data to init rootScope at page refresh

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

How can I store a User Json Object so that i can initialize my `$rootScope.user` Json Object with the stored data after page refresh?

It should be stored as long as the browser window is open, so that the user can do things like a page refresh.

Thanks for helping :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably looking for [Web Storage](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp). There is even an [Angular module](https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage) for this!